# Django, nose, coverage - skipping certain modules

Tags: django, code-coverage, nose

I'm running nose and coverage on a Django app.

I've got a structure that looks something like this:

```
app
..__init__.py
..tests.py
..views.py
..models.py
..urls.py
..admin.py
```

Now, if I run the normal `manage.py test app` the tests in tests.py run without an issue. However, when I hook up nose as a test suite, the tests stop running (it finds and executes 0 tests).

This is *not* a nose configuration issue, as I have the exact same configuration running successfully on *other*, similarly structured django apps.

Now, if I take the `tests.py` file and change it into a directory named "tests" and put all of those tests into `__init__.py`, the tests run using nose.

To further complicate things, when those tests DO run as an `__init__` file, the coverage report is only showing coverage on `admin.py`, `__init__.py`, and `models.py` but it is skipping `admin.py` and `views.py`. As above, this is *not* a nose config issue, as I have the suite running inclusively with other, similarly structured apps and it's performing as expected.

Any clues? I'm banging my head against the wall on this one...

Comment: One thing I have noticed: coverage ignore some modules if you didn't imported they directly from your tests. Probably coverage ignore all those modules which wasn't imported before tests started (exclude packages - folder with \_\_init\_\_.py), but some of them can be imported automatically by django-nose or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried forcing django_nose to run certain tests by specifying an argument called --tests? Maybe of of these will work:

```
python manage.py test --tests=tests
python manage.py test --tests=app.tests
python manage.py test --tests=app.tests:MyUnitTestClass
```